# Google Cloud API for user

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-iam

I am AWS fella, so I have no knowledge if this is possible with Google Cloud and googling has failed me so far.

I have a user that I added to a bucket `foo` with role `bar`. All I see at the moment is that I get GUI access for bucket `foo`, now how/can I generate API key for my user so I can use it with resources allowed with role `bar`?

All I see as an option at the moment is creating service account which does not sound proper to me, but i might be wrong.

Comment: Google Cloud no longer supports (or reducing support for) API Keys. Your authorization choices are OAuth (user account credentials) or service accounts or presigned urls for Cloud Storage. If this is a user who will be using Google Cloud console or tools use OAuth User Credentials. If this is a software program, use a service account.

Comment: ty, that helps for sure, will go into figuring it out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google Cloud no longer supports (or reducing support for) API Keys. Your authorization choices are OAuth (user account credentials) or service accounts or presigned urls for Cloud Storage. If this is a user who will be using Google Cloud console or tools use OAuth User Credentials. If this is a software program, use a service account.